# The LSDDetector and some related function couldn't work in Opencv 4.1.0

Tags: opencv

I want to use the LSDDetector to detect the line features in the image and use the BinaryDescriptorMatcher to describe them so that I can finish the line feature matching. It works properly in opencv version 4.0.x, but the opencv version in my pc updated to 4.1.0 now. Then the code cannot work.

The error notice is as follows:

> OpenCV(4.1.0) /tmp/opencv-20190413-55052-1xilkvg/opencv-4.1.0/modules/imgproc/src/lsd.cpp:143: error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) Implementation has been removed due original code license issues in function 'LineSegmentDetectorImpl'

```
def lsdMatching(img1, img2):
    img1_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img1,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    img2_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img2,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    detector = cv2.line_descriptor.LSDDetector_createLSDDetector()
    keylines = detector.detect(img1_gray,2,2)
```

Comment: Please read the error message: "Implementation has been removed due original code license issues in function 'LineSegmentDetectorImpl'". The implementation has been removed since the LSD algorithm is licensed under the GNU Affero General Public License while OpenCV is BSD-3. They are not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

LSD detector had been removed completely from the source tree since 4.1.0 release (see opencv/opencv@3ba49cc). Switch two previous versions such as 3.4.5 works for me.